# Android in-app billing: securing purchase token

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I am implementing subscription in my android app. Assume that my service name is FOO. People login to FOO with a FOO username and they can subscribe to some premium FOO services.

The [`purchaseToken`](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#implementing) I get from the Google Play is an important element that I store in a local DB and as well send it to my remote server through an HTTPS connection. My remote server will call the [get API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/purchases/get) to validate the receipt of purchase and depending on the result we activate a set of premium services for that FOO username.

Now my question is, if a user tries to hack around and gets `purchaseToken` from DB or by sniffing the packets, he can validate it for a different FOO username. Isn't it? How can I make sure that it's always safe?

I can think of a few options but I'm not sure which one is best and safest and foolproof.

First, obfuscate/encrypt while storing. It is still just RE-able. With a bit of effort, it is hackable.

Second, make sure that `purchaseTokens` are unique on the server side. Even though it seems OK to me I'm a bit paranoid and I'm not sure if this is going to cause other problems.

What do you think?